# Importing library in Python called by PHP

Tags: php, python, python-import, cross-language

I'm trying to call a Python script from a PHP file, but it fails when I have to load a local library. My PHP is able to call my python if it doesn't load local libraries, and my python script works when launched manually.

Here are minimal (non) working files :

`index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      $command = escapeshellcmd ("./getter.py") ;
      $output = shell_exec ($command) ;
      echo "<p>$output</p>" ;
    ?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

`getter.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import got
if __name__ == "__main__" :
  print "Python2 working"
```

Where `got` is the famous local library.

When I manually launch my `./getter.py` the print is happening, but my webpage doesn't display anything.
When I comment the `import got` the webpage is also displaying the print.

Additional information :

- OS : Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Server web : nginix 1.14.0
- PHP : 7.2
- Python : 2.7.15rc1
- I am a newbee in web language so I am not aware of the debbuging tools yet
- There is no problems when importing a non-local library (such as `os`, `csv`, or others)
- I tried to replace the `$command = escapeshellcmd ("./getter.py") ; $output = shell_exec ($command) ;` by a simple `$output = shell_exec ("./getter.py") ;`
- I tried to replace `#!/usr/bin/env python2` by `#!/usr/bin/python2`
- When I ask PHP or Python to give me their current working directory, they both return than they are in `/var/html/www/test`, as planned.

Here is a folder tree :

```
├── getter.py
├── got
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── manager
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── TweetCriteria.py
│   │   └── TweetManager.py
│   └── models
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── Tweet.py
├── index.php
├── __init__.py
└── lib
    ├── __init__.py
    └── toto.py
```

Thank you much.

Comment: Where are `getter.py` and `got` in relation to each other, and to the PHP file? How did you install `got`?

Comment: Everything is in the same folder /var/www/html/test belongs to root user.
got was installed with a git clone

I just tried to create a `lib` folder, containing a `toto.py` and a `__init__..py`, and including lib.toto does work in PHP. I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Sorry but that is really unclear. Can you please update your question with the directory structure (eg using `tree`).

Comment: OK, just did that.

Comment: Change `import got` to `from . import got` and try again. Can you also try to add the log error?

Comment: I got it.
`Nginx` was executing as root, which didn't get all the requirements to run `got`, I needed to reinstall the requirements for all users.
Thanks for the time you spend helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually caused by a dependency problem. Some required libraries where installed only for some users. And Nginx couldn't access it as root, while the normal user could.

Comment: I switched from apache to nginx and i am calling a python script to execute. For me the problem was fixed by simply install the required python-library with the "-H" parameter. Like that: sudo -H pip install <packageName>